# Wait for a task in multiple tasks at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task

Imagine an initialization task and two workers:

```
var Init = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
});
var TaskB = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Init;
    Console.WriteLine("B finished waiting");
    await Task.Delay(10000000);
});
var TaskC = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Init;
    Console.WriteLine("C finished waiting");
    await Task.Delay(10000000);
});
```

After 1 second, `TaskB` and `TaskC` are printing to the console and continuing as expected.

However, when the task which finishes first uses no asynchronous methods after awaiting Init, the other task `await Init` call does not finish:

```
var Init = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
});
var TaskB = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Init;
    Console.WriteLine("B finished waiting");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
});
var TaskC = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Init;
    Console.WriteLine("C finished waiting");
    while (true) { }
});
```

The latter example prints only "C finished waiting" to the console. Why is that so?

Comment: Not reproducible: https://ideone.com/hWZxtZ

Comment: I pushed my demo to github: https://github.com/Trolldemorted/DotnetCoreTest/blob/master/DotnetCoreTest/Program.cs It is fully reproducible on my W10 desktop. Edit: not *fully* reproducible, it works fine when B finishes first (obviously)

Comment: If you use 2 whiletrue-loops it also reproduces on ideone.com: https://ideone.com/Gh26EG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Behind the scenes, async/await builds a state machine based on task continuations. You can mimic it using `ContinueWith` and a bit of ingenuity (the details are beyond the scope of this answer).

What you need to know is that it uses continuations, and that continuations - by default - happen syncrhonously, one at a time.

In this case, both B and C are creating continuations on `Init`. These continuations will run after the other. Thus, when C continues first and goes into the infinite loop, it prevents B to continue.

---

The solution? Well, other than avoiding infinite loops, you could use a task with asynchronous continuations. A simple way to do it on top of `Task.Run` is the following:

```
var Init = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}).ContinueWith(_ => { }, TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
```

---

**Addendum**

As per OP comment, the infinite loop represent a blocking call. We can solve that situation by a different approach:

```
var TaskC = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Init;
    Console.WriteLine("C finished waiting");
    await Task.Run(() => {while (true) { }});
});
```

This way, the blocking call is not int the continuation of `Init` (instead, it would be in a continuation of a continuation), and thus it won't prevent other continuations of `Init` to run.

Comment: Interesting! Unfortunately one worker is calling a blocking library function right after init, but you ContinueWith hint really helps!

Comment: @Benni I have extended the answer. If there is not an async API for that blocking call, consider the approach I present there.

Comment: Thanks! Is it superior to using ContinueWith, though?

Comment: @Benni Running continuation in parallel needs more care to make sure two continuations running at the same time won't step on each other toes (introduce race conditions), if you are not confortable saying it won't happen, I would advice to not use it. In that regard, running them syncrhonously is safer, thus, it makes sense that it is the default... in fact, it used to be the only option. `RunContinuationsAsynchronously` will let you take advantage of parallelism - which may or may not yield better performance, and remember that it usually means using more threads from the thread pool.